# How to run external testcase(Class,junit) in java program?

Tags: java, junit

How to run external testcase(Class,junit) in java program?

Comment: What do you mean by external testcase?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to run JUnit tests through a Java program, you could use the **[JUnitCore](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc_40/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html)** class

> JUnitCore is a facade for running tests.
>   It supports running JUnit 4 tests, JUnit 3.8.x tests, and mixtures.
>   To run tests from the command line, run:

(windows)

```
java -cp /path/to/junit.jar;/path/to/yourTextClasses org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestClass1 TestClass2 ....
```

(Unix)

```
java -cp /path/to/junit.jar:/path/to/yourTextClasses org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestClass1 TestClass2 ....
```

> For one-shot test runs, use the static method `runClasses(Class[])`.

Make sure you have junit.jar in your classpath, and the jar or classes of your external tests also in the the classpath.

That way you can execute them from the command-line (which may not be  what you are after) or directly within your java program.

```
JUnitCore.runClasses(TestClass1,TestClass2,...)
```

Comment: classpath parameter should be -> -cp "1;2" or -cp "1:2"

Comment: @h3xStream: you are right. I have edited and fixed the answer.