# Run JUnit Test on a file not in project folder

Tags: java, junit

I would like to run a JUnitTest on a .java file which is not in the project folder. So far I implemented running the test succesfully if the .java file which should be tested is in the project folder:

```
public Result testAStudent(Class aTestClass){
    Result r = org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(aTestClass);
    return r;
}
```

How can I run the test on a file which is not in my project folder? I found a [possibility to do it in the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197882/how-to-run-external-testcaseclass-junit-in-java-program), but I do not want to execute shell commands. Is there a way to do it "internal"?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to test a class that's not in your project?

Comment: we have to write a programm checking students' programms. each homework will be saved in a different folder. For saving time I would like to crawl through these homework folders and test them automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests allow testing compiled class files. Not `.java` source files. For the test to be able to use (and thus test) a given class, this class must be available in the classpath.

So, when launching JUnit, make sure to have the directory or jar file containing the classes to test in the classpath.

Comment: So each time I test another file I change the classpath so it points to the file I would want to run my test on?

Comment: Assuming all your students have all written a class with the same name, and you want to test each of these classes, yes. Except the classpath refers to directories and jar files. Not to .class files.

Comment: No, what I get will be .java files. Ok, I will try that, thanks!

Comment: Don't you understand that you can't test code that is not even compiled? You need to compile java source files to be able to execute the code they contain. I don't want to be rude, but that's what you typically learn in your very first Java lesson. How comes you're teaching Java and checking students work if you don't know that?

Comment: Don't mind being rude -one gets used to it asking questions. Actually we are still students developing this programm as a project for a teacher - so I'm still learning. And I will compile the files before testing on them, thanks.

Comment: Ah OK. I'm reassured then. So, you'll probably have to make a shell script that loops through the students directories, compiles the java source files for one student, then launches JUnit with the appropriate classpath for this student, then goes to the next student directory.